# How do I get pqxx (the C++ API for Postgres) to work when my database authentication requires a password?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I installed C++, Postgres, and postgresql-devel on CentOS 7.3.  I installed libpqxx-4.0 too.

I then created this add_employee.cxx file and based it on the "brief example" [here](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/wiki).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main(int, char *argv[])
{
  pqxx::connection c("dbname=foobar user=jdoe password=smartpassword");
  pqxx::work txn(c);

  pqxx::result r = txn.exec(
    "SELECT id "
    "FROM Employee "
    "WHERE name =" + txn.quote(argv[1]));

  if (r.size() != 1)
  {
    std::cerr
      << "Expected 1 employee with name " << argv[1] << ", "
      << "but found " << r.size() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  int employee_id = r[0][0].as<int>();
  std::cout << "Updating employee #" << employee_id << std::endl;

  txn.exec(
    "UPDATE EMPLOYEE "
    "SET salary = salary + 1 "
    "WHERE id = " + txn.quote(employee_id));

  txn.commit();
}
```

I compiled it with this:

```
c++ add_employee.cxx -lpqxx -lpq
```

I ran ./a.out and saw this:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'pqxx::broken_connection'   what():  FATAL:  Peer authentication
>   failed for user "foobar"
>
> Aborted

I normally need a password for the database role "jdoe" to log in.  What do I do to get around the error?  I want to have a C++ program log in automatically.  I do not have passwordless authentication into the database.   Is there a way to have this C++ program log into the Postgres database despite requiring a password?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this has little to do with your C++ code, and more with you the server is set up.

As I recall, API access always goes over the network so make sure you `pg_hba.conf` file is correct.

One way I found useful for testing: access from another machine on the same local network.

Comment: I think my pg_hba.conf file is set up correctly.  I have Postgres on one server.  I'm trying to do this locally.  Can you elaborate on how I would try from another machine?  That would introduce a new complexity from my local attempt.

Comment: I found that `psql` _on the same machine_ is not a valid test as it uses a socket. Using `psql` on _another machine_ is a valid test as it will use tcp/ip, which is what your C++ code will use.  So trying from another machine, explicitly pointing back via the host argument, helped me in the past.

Comment: And I just tried again from machine _laptop_ to machine _server_. Besides `psql` I also had to  install and ident daemon and my `pg_hba.conf` has ident set for the local network.  After that ... it all works swimmingly.  As does programmatic access on the server itself.